# Show that there is a step function $h$ and a measurable subset $F$ of $I$ for which $h=\chi_E \text{ on $F$ and } m(I \setminus F) < \varepsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $I$ be closed and bounded interval and $E$ measurable subset of $I$. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Show that there is a step function $h$ on $I$ and a measurable subset $F$ of $I$ for which $$h=\chi_E \text{ on $F$ and } m(I \setminus F) < \varepsilon.$$

I'm instructed to use the following theorem.

> Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite outer measure. Then for each $\varepsilon >0$ there is a finite disjoin collection of open intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$ for which if $\mathcal{O}=\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$, then $$m^*(E \setminus \mathcal{O}) + m^*( \mathcal{O} \setminus E) < \varepsilon.$$

Now this seems to be for outer measures and what I'm working with is the Lebesgue measure. Since $E$ a subset of set that's bounded I assume that $E$ has a finite outer measure so I can use the theorem. What I have is then that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k = \mathcal{O}$ and that $$m^*(E \setminus \mathcal{O}) + m^*( \mathcal{O} \setminus E) < \varepsilon.$$ Now I'm bit lost. I have no idea what is this set $F$ I'm supposed to construct and what's the role of the step function $h$ here?